# How to convert array to object

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

First, I have tried to find solution within the source here but couldn't find what I am looking so posting as a new question. Thanks for your help

I want to convert Array to Object. Here is what I am getting output

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [username] => robustsolver
            [first_name] => John
            [last_name] => Smith
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [username] => pickypacker
            [first_name] => Peter
            [last_name] => Packer
        )

)
```

So if I want any column for all users than I have to write code `$users[0]->first_name;` which gives me only one item. But what I am looking is to use `$users->first_name` and this should return an array of all user's column (here is first_name)

Hope I have explain in better way. :S

Comment: try get_object_vars()

Comment: so you have an array of objects and you want to convert it to an object of arrays, is that right?

Comment: @aneesh getting error `Message: get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given`

Comment: @Ibrahim.I Yes, that's what I am trying to do so. Could you help me please? And yeah thank to learn me the terminology for such array. Like `an array of objects` I was confused how to say it in words. Thanks again.. :)

Comment: first you know the structure of your objects, right? I mean you know all the properties of the object

Comment: Yes I do, but if any specific things you want to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this where `$arr` is your array:

```
function filter_callback($element) {
    return $element->first_name;
}
$result= array_map('filter_callback', $arr);
```

From a quick test, this seems to work. It keeps objects of the array without your wanted property but its value is set to `NULL`. Not sure if that's what you want but you can edit the `filter_callback` to remove such elements.

Comment: Yeah I think I just figured the question out... Not sure if this is doable with a single `array_map` call though...

Comment: I got the output as an array. Let me try others too.. Thanks

Comment: Is there any way to set column name `first_name` as a parameter somewhere so I can set as per my need?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this will work (not tested):

```
$arr = array(...); // array of objects (in)
$obj = new Object; // object of arrays (out)

foreach($arr as $a) {
    foreach(get_object_vars($a) as $k=>$v) {
        if(!property_exists($obj, $k)) {
            $obj->{$k} = array();
        }
        $obj->{$k}[] = $v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

consider defining a new class:

```
class User_objects
{
    public $first_name;
    public $username;
    public $last_name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->first_name = array();
        $this->username = array();
        $this->last_name = array();
    }
}
```

then:
consider `$array_of_objects` to be your array of objects (input).

```
$users = new User_objects();

foreach ($array_of_objects as $object)
{
     $users->first_name[] = $object->first_name; // append to array
     $users->last_name[] = $object->last_name;
     $users->username[] = $object->username;
}
```

then you can get your array from `$users->first_name`

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple helper function that will aid in the columns you wish to select:

```
function prop_selector($prop)
{
    return function($item) use ($prop) {
        return $item->{$prop};
    };
}

$first_names = array_map(prop_selector('first_name'), $users);
$last_names = array_map(prop_selector('last_name'), $users);
```

Comment: Its giving `Message: Undefined variable: prop` any idea

Comment: @JatinSoni I thought you wanted to have the property name as a parameter, so a bit surprised to see you've accepted the other answer instead ...

Comment: Not actually, sorry about the confusion. but I wanted an object as a return value with having ability to set column name as parameter if needed.

Comment: @JatinSoni Then it seems that DarkSide's answer is what you want.